# Distributing items evenly

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

With a simple setup like the one in the picture with a double chest connected to 2 hoppers, you can get stacks of items evenly distributed. In this setup half would end up in each single chest.

[image]

In my single player world (1.12) I have made a sorting system and I want half my cobblestones to go to a smelter and the other half to go to a storage chest. My sorting system has hopper lines going in from all my farms, mines and so on so all my items pass that way. Using this mechanism worked really fine during testing, I plonked stacks of stone into the input chest and I could add more chests and hoppers to divert ¼ or other fractions as I pleased.

However, when I hooked it all up to my supply line it only sent items to the first hopper. I realized the problem is that the double chest only receives one item at a time so it will always get sent to the same hopper.

Is there a simple way to remedy this? Can I make it retain items until there is a stack of 2 before sending them to the double chest?

Comment: Just for completeness, this seems to work for all kinds of incoming item streams: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoARdQOW--4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this redstone solution.  I have sent an entire chest through a few times to verify operation.

Two hoppers one above the other, pointed in opposite directions.  It uses a clock to intermittently lock the bottom hopper:
[image: Example]

The repeater is set to 3 ticks.  You can adjust repeater to get different rates out if you ever want to deviate from 50/50.

Comment: I just tried it out in my test world and it seems to work really well for my purposes. I will go ahead and incorporate it in my sorting system.
Thank you.

Comment: @KarstenJensen If this answer helped you out the most, don't forget to accept it by clicking the little green check mark next to the votes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a minecart with hopper to distribute items evenly. You let it collect a few items with a loading station (for example [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-cWqvP8rw0)), then you let it run over a row of hoppers and these hoppers lead into different hopper lines in all the directions you want.

Comment: Minecarts work. They have their own issues but in my previous design I did do exactly that. I wanted something simpler and less noisy this time around but I can still recommend that approach.