# How do I evenly distribute items between 4 furnaces without minecart?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The problem I'm having is evenly distributing cactus from my farm into my xp smelter.  Because the cactus flows into the hopper minecart relatively slowly, it is filling the first furnace on the minecart track more than the others.  I'd really like to do 5 or 6 or n furnaces, but I'll settle for a solution that involves 4.

One thing I tried was simply two hoppers underneath a chest, then 2 hoppers underneath each of the output chests (so 4 hoppers on this layer), but two of the furnaces filled up while two completely did not...  something like an expansion of [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/314697/distributing-items-evenly).

Comment: Why is that question and answer insufficient for your needs?  It explains why setting up Chests/Hoppers like you described won't work, and how to fix it...

Comment: @John , the method described there works for 2 chests

Comment: So, 2 chests, then you have 2 hopper lines, and you split it using two more chests to 4 hopper lines.....

Comment: Would you be interested in a solution to the minecart problem instead? It sounds like you maybe have a setup issue. If you share an image of your current setup I could take a look.

Comment: @Johonn I believe the issue is related to the fact that the cactus enters the system randomly, and as such piles up in the first furnace.  I've heard of many people having the same problem.  I'm sure if I let the system fill up everything would be fine

Comment: @ChootsMagoots I see, so essentially the minecart is taking off without having one item per furnace in it. I believe there are ways to hold it until it has the right multiple of items, but I'd have to look more into that.

Comment: I got this to work by firstly distributing a double chest into two other double chests, then having a clock that activated slowly to distribute those chests into the furnaces.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple solution for evenly distriuting items between furnaces through minecarts. This system works for up to 15 furnaces:

[image: Evenly Distribute Hoppers]

The input chest feeds to a line of sideways hoppers that are all pointing into the next. The final hopper is also pointed sideways, not downwards.

The last hopper's contents are being monitored by a redstone comparator. The comparator's output feeds directly into a redstone torch, which unpowers a redstone line that is disabling a line of downwards-pointing hoppers directly underneath the row of sideways hoppers. These hoppers lead into the furnaces.

This machine works under the premise that hoppers always flow one item at a time. This means that if a constant stream of items begins flowing through the top line, then by the time the first item reaches the hopper with the comparator, there will be one item per hopper. The system then unpowers the redstone, causing the items to "drop in" to the hopper and furnace immediately below.

Comment: Would you like a similar system for automated fuel loading too? Just comment, and I can add this to the image.

Comment: I found this video that is of the same concept, but includes a solution for both items and fuel. https://youtu.be/UXgJNgaSTC4 I should note, that while it *should* distribute items evenly, there is some sort of bug/artifact from the way Minecraft handles hoppers, which results in items skipping over one of the furnaces. As far as I've been able to research, there is no known solution for this problem. Ilmango also provided the following tutorial for a 23 or 46 furnace super smelter, which supposedly solves the skipped furnace issue, but it's a lot more complex. https://youtu.be/NTkdxZRVbzI